# IN operator or JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql

I have written below queries

```
Query 1
select * from TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b on a.ID = b.ID
where b.TEST is not null
and b.NAME = 'TESTING' and 
b.LAST_NAME like 'A%';

Query 2
select * from TABLE_A a 
where 
ID IN (
select ID
from TABLE_B b where
b.TEST is not null
and b.NAME = 'TESTING' and 
b.LAST_NAME like 'A%';);
```

Any suggestions on which is better in terms of performance and load on the database server. Table_A and Table_B have millions of records.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW. Those queries may return different results.

Comment: @jarlh  I am using oracle 12c

Comment: @jarlh It returned me same results

Comment: _May_, depending on data. (e.g. many to many...)

Answer (score 1):

For the first query, do not use `left join`:

```
select *
from TABLE_A a join
     TABLE_B b on a.ID = b.ID
where b.TEST is not null and
      b.NAME = 'TESTING' and 
      b.LAST_NAME like 'A%';
```

The `where` clause undoes the outer join anyway.

Next, the two queries return different result sets:

- The `join` version returns columns from both `a` and `b`; the `in` version returns columns only from `a`.
- The `join` version can return duplicates if matching rows are duplicated in `b`.  The `in` version does not return duplicates generated by `b`.

My advice is to use the query that implements what you actually need.  That said, I recommend using `exists` rather than `in` because it is usually easier to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation it made me to understand the difference. In terms off performance and load on database server which query will be preferred.

Comment: @Kiran: As has been mentioned, the two queries return different result sets, so it doesn't matter which is faster. You'd use the one the result set of which matches your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries return different data, so there is no use comparing them.

Let's take an example where the result set is the same instead. We are looking for employees working in a branch in Great Britain:

### IN

```
select *
from employees
where department_id in (select department_id from departments where country = 'GB');
```

### EXISTS

```
select *
from employees e
where exists
(
  select null
  from departments d
  where d.department_id = e.department_id and d.country = 'GB'
);
```

### JOIN

```
select e.*
from employees e
join departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id
where d.country = 'GB';
```

Most DBMS have an optimizer built in looking for the optimal way to get the data. As the three queries look for the same employees, a good DBMS should come up with the same plan for them. A not so good DBMS may come up with different plans and one would have to look at the executions plans then to see which one is best.

I much prefer the first query over the others. It is very readable ("select employees where the departments is in the set of GB departments") and thus well maintainable. Why write a more complicated query instead? And why join if we are not really interested in the joined result?

Here is another example: All departments where some person named Smith works.

### IN

```
select *
from departments
where department_id in (select department_id from employees where last_name = 'Smith');
```

### EXISTS

```
select *
from departments d
where exists
(
  select null
  from employees e
  where e.department_id = d.department_id and e.last_name = 'Smith'
);
```

### JOIN

```
select distinct d.*
from departments d
join employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
where e.last_name = 'Smith';
```

Same thing as before. The `IN` query is the most readable one. `EXISTS` is a viable alternative. But the join even needs `DISTINCT` now, because we'd get departments multiple times otherwise, if more than one Smith works there. This is additional work for the DBMS (sorting the results in order to find and eliminate duplicates) and it consumes not only CPU, but also memory, because we build a large intermediate result first only to reduce it later. It is way better to only select the data we really want from the start. Still, a good optimizer may detect this and come up with the same plan as for the `IN` query. It's just less likely.